# Ajax not getting data from database in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, ajax, codeigniter, mysqli

I am trying to populate form fields inside a bootstrap modal for updating data in the database using ajax. I am not getting any data instead of modal popup with empty fields. Please check my code and help me to figure out the problem.

Here is the controller function.

```
public function edit(){
    $output = array();
    $this->load->model("crud_data");
    $patient_id = $this->input->post("patient_id");
    $data = $this->crud_data->fetch_single($patient_id);
    foreach ($data as $row) {
        $output["name"] = $row->name;
        $output["age"]  = $row->age;
    }
    echo json_encode($output);
}
```

Here is the fetch_single modal function.

```
public function fetch_single($patient_id){
$this->db->where("patient_id", $patient_id);
$query = $this->db->get('patients');
return $query->result();
}
```

Ajax for the functionality

```
$(document).on("click", '.edit', function(){
  var patient_id =  $(this).attr("patient_id");
  $.ajax({
    url:"<?php base_url(); ?>crud/edit",
    method:"POST",
    data:{'patient_id':patient_id},
    dataType:"json",
    success:function(data){
      $("#edit").modal("show"); 
      $("#name").val(data.name);
      $("#age").val(data.age);
      $("#patient_id").val(patient_id); 
      $(".modal-title").html("Edit User")
    },
  });
});
```

I want to get data in fields so i can update it.

Comment: call this $("#edit").modal("show"); after assigning values to modal

Comment: No luck after doing the thing you suggest

Comment: what do you get if use `console.log(data)` ?

Comment: use `success:function(response){ console.log(response)}` to check out your response.
also you can view response in the `network` tab when use `inspect element`

Comment: @AliQorbani console.log saying "Array(0)".

Comment: You are showing multiple records in the popup?

Comment: @DanishAli Obviously

Comment: @MuhammadAhtsham I mean the record of more than one user? Because you are using loop to get record

Comment: @DanishAli No Just for single

Comment: as @DanishAli said you should use `$query->row()` in your model. then. you can set header of output to be json forced. `$this->output->set_header('application/json');` and again check your result in `console.log`

Comment: @AliQorbani Could you please add it as complete answer with code

Comment: @MuhammadAhtsham data:({patient_id:patient_id}),//changed line

Comment: Are you getting any response ?

Answer (score 0):

```
public function edit(){
    $output = array();
    $this->load->model("crud_data");
    $patient_id = $this->input->post("patient_id");
    $data = $this->crud_data->fetch_single($patient_id);
    $output["name"] = $data ->name;
    $output["age"]  = $data ->age;
    $this->output->set_content_type('application/json');
    $this->output->set_output(json_encode($output));
}
```

this code must be correct if your model and database is correctly do the job.

Comment: Still no luck...Getting Empty array in console

Comment: what will you get on postman direct post to your controller? 
`localhost/ci_project/patients/edit/` and data field `patient_id = 1` ?

Comment: I am getting [ ] empty array too there

Comment: check your database has any data or not. 
then if has use code below in your model 
`$this->db->select()
->from('patients')
->where("patient_id", $patient_id);
$query = $this->db->get();`

Answer (score 0):

In success of ajax you didnt parse data as you sent json_encode from controller.
So Parse json_encode in success and then add data to modal.

```
 var parse_data = JSON.parse(data);
```

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

**Controller**

If you are getting only one row then don't use loop

```
public function edit(){
$output = array();
$this->load->model("crud_data");
$patient_id = $this->input->post("patient_id");
$data = $this->crud_data->fetch_single($patient_id);
$output["name"] = $data ->name;
$output["age"]  = $data ->age;
echo json_encode($output);
}
```

**Model**

To get only one row use `row()` not `result()`

```
public function fetch_single($patient_id){
  $this->db->where("patient_id", $patient_id);
  $query = $this->db->get('patients');
  return $query->row();
}
```

**Ajax Success Function**

Load modal after assigning values to input fields

```
success:function(data){ 
  $("#name").val(data.name);
  $("#age").val(data.age);
  $("#patient_id").val(patient_id); 
  $(".modal-title").html("Edit User");
  $("#edit").modal("show");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

i cann't tell you what you wrong but it easy to debug. first, you can console data received in ajax.In success function, you can console data. if it empty, you will check your php function. Check input $patient_id isset, and check  out put of 
`$this->crud_data->fetch_single($patient_id);`

brief, you should check step by step to find your mistake